# Is there a way to tell how postgresql uses an index?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table with an index:

```
create index on foo (a, b, c);
```

When searching for a and b Postgres can use the index to quickly look up the rows:

```
test=# explain analyze select a from foo where a = 3 and b = 4;
 Index Only Scan using foo_a_b_c_idx on foo  (cost=0.43..486.83 rows=120 width=4) (actual time=0.141..23.981 rows=59049 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((a = 3) AND (b = 4))
   Heap Fetches: 59049
 Total runtime: 25.894 ms
```

While searching for b and c is much slower, since it has to linearly scan the whole index (or table):

```
test=# explain analyze select a from foo where b = 4 and c = 5;
 Index Only Scan using foo_a_b_c_idx on foo  (cost=0.43..121987.32 rows=120 width=4) (actual time=7.377..159.793 rows=59049 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((b = 4) AND (c = 5))
   Heap Fetches: 59049
 Total runtime: 160.735 ms
```

However the query plans look equal in both cases (both are called "Index Only Scan" with some "Index Condition").. Is it possible to tell if access is possible in logarithmic or linear time (without having to look at each index definition)?

Other database systems are much more explicit about how they are using an index. In MS SQL the first query would be an "Index Seek" (fast) while the second one would be an "Index Scan" (slow). In Sqlite the first one would be a "SEARCH TABLE foo USING COVERING INDEX" (fast) while the second one would be a "SCAN TABLE foo USING COVERING INDEX" (slow).

Comment: The reason is that `b,c` are not at the leading edge of the index and thus Postgres needs to scan more index blocks in order to check if the rows meet the condition. If you really need the second query to be as fast as the first, you will need a second index on (b,c,a). You might also want to run `explain (analyze true, verbose true, buffers true)` which will show you more details on the number of IOs Postgres is doing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that doesn't answer my question. i know why one query is faster than the other one. my question was: since the query plans are equal in both cases (except of the index cond.) how can i tell which one will be fast (log time) or slow (linear time)? i tried "explain verbose" but that doesn't output that information either.

Comment: Did you include the `buffers true` for the analyze as in my example ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes i did, output is here: http://pastebin.com/e5qfZTsZ how can i tell from that if the lookup was fast or slow (without manually checking how the indexes are defined)?

Comment: Does the line `Buffers: shared hit=228 read=18541 written=1` differ between the two queries? (Btw: do you know: http://explain.depesz.com ?)

Comment: they differ, but isn't that irrelevant? in production there's only one query and one query plan you get to look at. normally you should be able to tell from this one query plan if the query is performing well or not. for example in this case sqlite would say it's "SCAN(ning the) TABLE", which is bad and i know i'll have to optimize the query (or the indexes) until it's "SEARCH(ing the) TABLE". all other databases systems i have worked with also display this information (ms sql: index seek vs. index scan,...). postgres seems to call both cases "Index Scan". do i have to live with that?

Comment: Then I have no idea what you are asking. If the plans differ, then what else do you want? But you might want to ask that question on the Postgres (-perormance) mailing list. As the developers read it, I'm sure if anybody knows the answer - you'd get it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the more detailed query plan options highlighted by @horse, the answer is: no. There is no hint or way to know besides having a basic understanding of how indexes work (and knowing your own schema, of course).

Comment: sorry but that doesn't answer my question. i know why one query is faster than the other one. my question was: since the query plans are equal in both cases (except of the index cond.) how can i tell which one will be fast (log time) or slow (linear time)? this is essential information in a query plan and other database systems display it (see above - ms sql, sqlite examples). where do i get this information in postgres, or do i have to manually check how each index is constructed?

Comment: I'm unsure what you expect as a reply to the question then, to be honest…

Comment: sorry maybe the question is unclear... for example sqlite says "SCAN TABLE USING INDEX" vs. "SEARCH TABLE USING INDEX", ms sql says "Index Scan" vs. "Index Seek" depending on how the index is used. postgres seems to call both cases "Index Scan". i'm trying to find out if i have to live with that and look at index definitions manually, or if there's a way to get this information out of postgres' query plans like in other database systems.

Comment: Oh, that! Apart from the more detailed query plan options highlighted by @horse, the answer is: no. There is no hint or way to know besides having a basic understanding of how indexes work (and knowing your own schema, of course).